# Force discharge with USB-C

Tags: macbook-pro, charger

I have a 2019 MacBook Pro with 4 USB-C ports. I also carry a Microsoft Surface with me. Sometimes, if the Surface is dying, I want to charge it with the MacBook Pro.

When I connect them via USB-C, the Surface charges the laptop. Is there a way to force the laptop to charge the Surface?

Thanks!